# Conga/DocuSign Integration using ID Check Signer Authentication

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to build a custom button for DocuSign/Conga to work, but my client wants to make sure that each recipient is using the ID Check Signer Authentication.  Problem is, I do not see a parameter for it.  I do see a parameter for Access Code, but that's about it.  How can I make sure that the recipients are having to complete the ID check authentication when sending via Conga?

Thanks!

Rachel

Comment: If this question pertains to the Conga AppExchange app then you'd have to follow up with Conga. If ID check is not available in their app then they would have to add it to their product, not DocuSign.  DocuSign offers these features but it's up to the integrated app on what to include.  As a side note though, through the DocuSign REST API if you want to code it up yourself then you can:  www.docusign.com/devcenter

Comment: Basically if you have a DocuSign account you can write up some api calls throughs Salesforce to do what you want to do, such as include ID checks for your recipients for instance

Comment: Okay.  I'll go ahead and look into that route.  Thank you!

Comment: One more thing I'll add- since DocuSign is a cloud based service there are many ways to access and interact with your data and documents. One other thing that is possible is that you create a DocuSign envelope through Conga or another system but save it as a draft and don't any recipients yet.  Then, through the DocuSign Console, one of the DOcuSign mobile apps, or another system you can then add recipients to that envelope and in turn add your ID check for whichever recipients you want...